# XPages repeat control header facet

Tags: header, xpages, repeat

I would like to insert a link with an event handler in the first `<th>` tag within the header facet. See example code below:

```
<xp:this.facets>
<xp:text disableTheme="true" xp:key="header" escape="false">
<xp:this.value><![CDATA[
<table class="table table-striped table-hover">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>
<xp:link escape="true" text="" id="link1">
    <i id="myIconLink" class="fa fa-square-o fa-lg text-success"></i>
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="partial" refreshId="tab2Panel">
    <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:
    sessionScope.selectAll = "1";
    }]]></xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler>

</xp:link>                                  
</th>
<th>Project Title</th>
<th>Type of Expenditure</th>    
<th>Plan Amount</th>
<th>Fiscal Year</th>    
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>]]>
</xp:this.value>
</xp:text>
<xp:text disableTheme="true" xp:key="footer"
escape="false">
<xp:this.value><![CDATA[
</tbody>
</table>]]></xp:this.value>
</xp:text>
</xp:this.facets>
```

The error I get is:

[image]

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't embed XPages tags inside the `value` property of a Computed Field. Any XPages tags need to be converted to Java objects by the compiler, but computed values are evaluated at runtime.

There are two possible approaches. Create the link as an HTML link calling a JSON RPC service http://www.notesin9.com/2014/05/21/tim-explains-json-rpc-codefortim/. This will ensure the HTML in the header facet is best practice.

The other is to use an xp:div for the facet instead of an xp:text, then use HTML or XPages components as required. This may probably be the easier option (unless you're fully conversant with JSON RPC service) but will affect the HTML that's outputted.

Comment: Thanks Paul. I just circumvented the problem by getting rid of the header and footer facets :)

Comment: Careful Dan - I agree the facet thing sucks, but skipping them and putting the repeat control inside <table> tags can create invalid HTML and possibly other issues.

Comment: FYI, to avoid xp:div affecting the HTML, you can use xp:panel disableOutputTag="true", which will output the panel contents with no container div. The disableOutputTag property was added in 8.5.3.

Comment: Maire - right you can do that, but if you do then does that not prevent the use of adding a Pager to the Repeat control?